# App works on emulator but crashes on S8

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, memory, bitmap

I am using 2 images for my app's splash screen. The logo in my ImageView (src) and the background in the layout(:background) and although my app works fine on the emulator it crashes on my phone(S8). Below you can see my xml file responsible for my splashScreen and the exception. From what I understand one of those images(or both?) are considered too large for my phone's memory? Their dimension however, are : 
logo(1305x641)
background(1688x1125).

Any ideas on how to fix this? I thought of providing different resolution versions of the images but I get lost in the process.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    tools:context="com.spdesigns.funfacts.SplashScreen">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
    android:layout_width="377dp"
    android:layout_height="293dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

Exception:

```
11-16 00:11:01.529 3688-3688/com.spdesigns.funfacts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.spdesigns.funfacts, PID: 3688
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(120362760bytes) bitmap.
                                                                      at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
                                                                      at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1420)
                                                                      at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
                                                                      at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1286)
                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18394)
                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17372)
                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18156)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3969)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3755)
                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18397)
                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17372)
                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18156)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3969)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3755)
                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17367)
                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18156)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3969)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3755)
                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17367)
                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18156)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3969)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3755)
                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17367)
                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18156)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3969)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3755)
                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17367)
                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18156)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3969)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3755)
                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18397)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:967)
                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17372)
                                                                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:722)
                                                                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:728)
                                                                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:836)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3181)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2977)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2565)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7189)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to load a 120 MB image into memory.
That's about 20 times bigger than any image that should ever be loaded.

It works fine on emulators, as they can utilize your computers memory, and perhaps have looser rules on memory consumption. But real devices are much stricter.

You should do the following:
1) Scale down the image further
2) Run PNGCrush on all images in your app. It's a program that reduces memory size of images without loosing quality (read their documentation for specifics)
3) Provide different size images for hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi densities. This way the system loads the appropriate image according to the screen size.

Comment: It is quite worrying that it worked on an emulator, kind of goes against its purpose! Also that would have been one hell of a play store download for a splash screen!

Comment: @Moonbloom I compressed both of them down to 30~`40KB each but I get the same error saying that I am trying to draw a 121500000byte bitmap. How is that possible since I compressed them?

Comment: Then it's not those images causing the error. Can you try to literally remove the images and not set them as background/logo, then run the app and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.

For anyone facing the same problem, just move your bitmap inside the mipmap-xxxhdpi folder. Since the image is too large and since I placed it inside the drawables dir, android considers this as an mdpi image. This causes android to scale it even more thus crashing the app and throwing the OutOfMemory Exception. By putting it inside the mipmap-xxxhdpi folder, android just scales it down to the target res.